# Not able to run Red language script on Linux

Tags: linux, rebol, red

I am trying to run following simple script file:

```
#! /usr/local/bin/red-063

Red []

print "testing"
quit
```

But I am getting following error:

```
** Script Error: Invalid compressed data - problem: -3
** Near: script: decapsulate 
if none? script
```

This error is mentioned on this page: https://github.com/red/red/blob/master/environment/system.red but details are not clear and also how it can be corrected.

Similar script for Rebol 2.7.8 works. Where is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with rebol not being able to unpack.  See [here](https://github.com/red/red/issues/543).

Essentially create a batch file or shell script in the directory as the red binary to invoke the red binary.

Comment: Will same work for Linux? There is another post: https://github.com/red/red/issues/1547

Comment: Did you try it?

Comment: I am away from my computer. Will try and respond ASAP.